# Необходимо передать input / output в GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, tkinter

У меня есть приложение написанное на *Python*. 
Я хочу **`создать графический интерфейс`** для своего приложения.

Код следующий:

```
question_variable = 'Question'
a = input('Ask me question: ')
if a == question_variable:
    print('Answer')
```

Мне нужно создать графический интерфейс и сделать так, чтобы вводимые пользователем данные и ответ программы отображались в графическом интерфейсе.

**П.С.** Я пытаюсь использовать *Tkinter* для этих целей, но все мои попытки разобраться в документации и поискать в интернете не дали свои плодов. Поэтому обращаюсь сюда. Спасибо.

Comment: Это сильно зависит от того, в каком конкретно виде вы хотите представить ввод/вывод. Одно окно или отдельное окно для ввода? Вывод замещает предыдущий или логирование типа консоли? И т.п. нюансы.

Comment: @GrAnd Спасибо за отклик! Я хочу, чтобы программа спрашивала у пользователя вопрос. Пользователь его задавал, а программа отвечала. Все это должно происходить в одном окне. После того как Программа ответила на вопрос пользователя, должна появиться кнопка например "Спросить еще", после чего все бы повторялось. Пользователь нажав на кнопку Спросить еще сбрасывал бы всю предыдущую информацию и снова увидел бы надпись Спроси у меня. Без новых окон

Answer (score 0):

На примитивном уровне это может выглядеть вот так:

```
import tkinter as tk

def ask():
    question = question_var.get()
    answer_var.set(f"Вы спросили '{question}'.\nДаже и не знаю что ответить.")
    show_answer()

def ask_question():
    if frames["answer"]:
        frames["answer"].destroy()
        frames["answer"] = None
    frames["question"] = tk.Frame(root)
    frames["question"].pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    tk.Label(frames["question"], text="Задайте ваш вопрос:").pack(padx=5, pady=5) 
    tk.Entry(frames["question"], width=40, textvariable=question_var).pack(padx=15, pady=5) 
    tk.Button(frames["question"], width=15, text="Спросить", command=ask).pack(padx=5, pady=[5,15]) 

def show_answer():
    if frames["question"]:
        frames["question"].destroy()
        frames["question"] = None
    frames["answer"] = tk.Frame(root)
    frames["answer"].pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    tk.Label(frames["answer"], textvariable=answer_var).pack(padx=5, pady=5) 
    tk.Button(frames["answer"], width=15, text="Спросить ещё", command=ask_question).pack(padx=5, pady=[5,15]) 
 
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Вопрошайка")
root.geometry("300x100")
 
frames = {"question":None, "answer":None}
question_var = tk.StringVar()
answer_var = tk.StringVar()
ask_question()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это ровно то, что мне нужно было.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем запустить мой пример, убедитесь, что вы установили *PyQt5*

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

*PyQt* — реализация фреймворка *Qt* для языка *Python*.

---

```
import sys
import wikipedia                                       # pip install wikipedia
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        wikipedia.set_lang("ru")
        
        self.label = QLabel("WikiBot", alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop )
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Sans Unicode")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: purple;")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")  
        
        self.topic = QLineEdit()
        self.topic.setPlaceholderText("Наберите что-нибудь ...")
        self.topic.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setBold(False)
        self.topic.setFont(font)
        self.topic.setObjectName("topic")
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Search")
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Corbel")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setBold(False)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run_search)

        self.txtarea = QTextEdit()
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MV Boli")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.txtarea.setFont(font)
        self.txtarea.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.txtarea.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Plain)
        self.txtarea.setReadOnly(True)
        self.txtarea.setObjectName("txtarea")        

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.topic, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.txtarea, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        
    def run_search(self):
        topic = self.topic.text()
        if not topic:
            self.txtarea.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.txtarea.setText("Вы не задали вопро, попробуйте еще раз.")
            return
        try:
            ans = wikipedia.summary(topic)            
            self.txtarea.setStyleSheet("color: Blue;")
            self.txtarea.setText(f'{topic}:\n\n{ans}')
        except:
            self.txtarea.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
            self.txtarea.setText("Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте еще раз.")
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]